# Branching and Merging Strategy

Tags: merge, branch, branching-and-merging

Our current branching and merging strategy:

Developers get latest from the **Develop** environment and create a feature branches.

Once Done, Developers merge changes back into **Develop**.

QA then clones **Develop** and calls it **QA**.

This is happening as the Sprint unfolds, so **Develop** will have been cloned multiple times.

If changes have been committed into **QA** (i.e. a new build/rename of **Develop** has occurred), they cannot be easily *removed* from QA because it would require an unraveling from **Develop** and another rebuild/clone.

The issue we're experiencing, is that there are often changes that are still being verified in **QA** at the end of the sprint, when it is time to present to the Change Control Board everything that is going to be in the release the following Tuesday. QA states that it would take *more* time to remove those changes than it would to just complete them. This creates risk.

What branching and merging strategies exist where if a ticket has failed QA, we can send the ticket back, and simply merge the change out of the **QA** environment? My intent is to get to "what makes it to Done in the sprint is what is in the next release."